# CMake build fails if it can't reach dependency repo

Tags: cmake, dependencies, git-tag

I have a CMake project (myapp) that depends on another CMake project (integrator). The integrator project is declared via the ExternalProject_Add and I use the GIT_TAG parameter to indicate what version of the integrator code to build. This works great while online. But, I run into build fail problems if I'm ever offline. It always fails the build if it can't reach the git repo, even if it had previously downloaded a copy of the repo. Can I make CMake stop reaching out to the GIT_TAG repo and just build with the code it had previously downloaded when I was last online?

Comment: What about setting the `UPDATE_DISCONNECTED 1` option? (see [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/module/ExternalProject.html)) As the docs say, "If UPDATE_DISCONNECTED is set, the update step is not executed automatically when building the main target. The update step can still be added as a step target and called manually. This is useful if you want to allow to build the project when you are disconnected from the network (you might still need the network for the download step). This is disabled by default."

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. It certainly sounds promising. I've read over that docs page multiple times and not seen that parameter. Sigh.

Comment: UPDATE_DISCONNECTED was just what I was looking for. Huge thanks, @DanMasek!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation of [ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/module/ExternalProject.html), there is an option named `UPDATE_DISCONNECTED`.

> If `UPDATE_DISCONNECTED` is set, the update step is not executed
>   automatically when building the main target. The update step can still
>   be added as a step target and called manually. This is useful if you
>   want to allow to build the project when you are disconnected from the
>   network (you might still need the network for the download step). This
>   is disabled by default.

Therefore, you should add the option setting

```
UPDATE_DISCONNECTED 1
```

to your `ExternalProject_Add` declaration in order to be able to work offline.